# How to get inotify working for bindfs?

Tags: linux, mount

Up to now I used this line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/home/ftp_user /home/app_user/mounts/ftp_user  fuse.bindfs  mirror=app_user 0    0
```

This works. The `app_user` can access the files of `ftp_user` like if the files would be his own files.

Now I would like to use inotify. The `app_user` listens for changes in the bind-mounted directory.

It works if `app_user` touches a file in `/home/app_user/mounts/ftp_user`.

But it does not work, if `ftp_user` touches a file in `/home/ftp_user`.

Is there way to get this working?

OS: Linux only.

## Update: use http if possible

If possible avoid clever inotify solutions. Receiving files via http is often better, since you can validate the files before accepting them. See [use http, avoid ftp/sftp/scp/rsync/smb/mail](https://github.com/guettli/programming-guidelines#use-http-avoid-ftpsftpscprsyncsmbmail)

Comment: Use ACLs, not FUSE bindfs. There's no need for a bind mount at all.

Comment: @MichaelHampton could you please give me a reason. Why are ACLs better than FUSE? What are the benefits?

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve can't be done.
Look at the https://bindfs.org/ and scroll down to "Known issues" section. You will see that

> inotify events are not triggered since FUSE doesn’t provide an API for
>   this

You can use inotify to monitor /home/ftp_user, but in this case user who is setting up watch will need to have access to this directory.

Comment: Maybe there is a solution which does not use FUSE?

Comment: You can possibly use ACL and add permissions to user app_user on /home/ftp_user dir and then setup inotify watch directly to /home/ftp_user dir. That of course would require mounting /home file system with ACL option.

Comment: Solution which does not use fuse is called ACL - Access Control Lists. Start reading here https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/ch-acls

Answer (score 1):

Doing it the other way round works:

The ftp_user gets the virtual (mounted) directory, and the app_user holds the real directory.

```
/home/ftp_user /home/app_user/import/ftp_user  fuse.bindfs  mirror=ftp_user 0    0
```

New files get created in the virtual directory (for example `/home/ftp_user/new.txt`). This triggers the inotify which runs as user `app_user`. In this example the file event gets created for `/home/app_user/import/ftp_user/new.txt`.

Comment: This works fantastically for me. I want to trigger resilio-sync running as its own user, but wasn't able to get it to working faster than the standard 10min scan. Doing it reverse here works great for triggering via inotify